# Extjs line graph

Tags: extjs, linegraph, yaxis

I want to visualize different company data in different colors against date of a line graph. 
The problem is the number of companies will change.

Let's say the input data will be like

```
data: [{ date: '2018-12-20', company1: 10, company2: 5, },{ date: '2018-12-21', company1: 10, company2: 10 }]
```

To visualize it the model will be like

```
    Ext.define('ABC.model.Job', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

fields: [

    {name: 'DATE', type: 'auto'}
    {name: '1', type: 'int'}
    {name: '2', type: 'int'}

],

proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    noCache: false,

    actionMethods: {'read': 'POST'},

    api: {
        read: utils.createUrl('api', 'read'),

    },

    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data'
    },

    listeners: {
        exception: function(proxy, response, operation) {
            App.showHttpError('Job ', response);
        }
    }
}
```

});

And the view portion of axes will be

Ext.define('ABC.view.Job', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',

```
requires: [
    'ABC.store.Job',        
],

border: false,
layout: {type:'vbox', pack:'start', align:'stretch'},

initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;



    me.jobStore2 = Ext.create('ABC.store.Job');




    Ext.apply(me, {
        items: [
            {
            xtype: 'chart',
            store: me.jobStore2,
            style: 'background: #fff',
            insetPadding: 40,
            animate: true,
            shadow: false,
            flex: 2,
            minHeight: 400,
            legend: {
                position: 'top',
                boxStrokeWidth: 0,
                labelFont: '12px Helvetica'
            },

            axes: [{
                type: 'Numeric',
                position: 'left',
                fields: ['1'],
                grid: true,
                minimum: 0, 


            }, {
                type: 'Category',
                position: 'bottom',
                fields: ['DATE'],
                grid: true,
            }],


            series: [{
            type: 'line',
            axis: 'left',
            title: '1',
            xField: 'DATE',
            yField: '1',
            style: {
                'stroke-width': 4
            },

        },
                    {
                type: 'line',
                axis: 'left',
                xField: 'DATE',
                border: false,
                flex:1,
                title: ['2'],
                yField: ['2'],

                  style: {
                'stroke-width': 4
            },

            }

                ]

    }
    });

    me.callParent(arguments);
}
```

});

What if the data contains lots of companies. How can I change the series? Instead of giving the detail of y axis again and again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ease of maintenance, you can just create an array containing the company names, and map it into both fields and axes:

```
var companies = ['company1', 'company2', ...];

Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: [{
        name: 'DATE', 
        type: 'auto'
    }].concat(
        companies.map(function(companyName) {
            return {
                name: companyName,
                type: 'int'
            };
        })
    )
});

    ...
    series: companies.map(function(companyName) {
        return {
            type: 'line',
            axis: 'left',
            title: '1',
            xField: 'DATE',
            yField: companyName,
            style: {
                'stroke-width': 4
            },
        }
    });
    ...
```

Comment: I am afraid, that is not working. Even the graph not loading

Comment: @Sahan Well, it is working for me in a similar setting. You may have to show more of your code for me to understand what issue you have with implementation.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I have edited my post with full of my code.  Could you please help to achieve

Comment: I have done. but now my problem is I want push company1, company2 inside the companies array in model instead of hard code it from the back end data part